# Connect MySQL container volume to existing data

Tags: mysql, database, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm trying to dockerize our website and I need to be able to connect the MySQL container to an existing database. I don't want to link my app container to a local DB but would rather use a volume to bring the data into the MySQL container. If what I'm trying to do makes sense could someone please help me. Below is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/app/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    container_name: pedestalpro_app
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./dockerfiles/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    env_file:
      - .env
    tty: true

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    depends_on:
      - app
    container_name: pedestalpro_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./public/:/var/www/public
      - ./dockerfiles/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    tty: true

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: pedestalpro_mysql
    volumes:
      - pedestalpro_db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./dockerfiles/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    env_file:
      - .env.mysql

volumes:
  pedestalpro_db:
```

Comment: I dont know if i got to understand your question. I don't think you can modify the content of a volume manually to copy/paste without actually accessing it using dockers internal folders.  Yet, if what you want is only to load an existing db into a volume, you can easily do this by starting your MySQL with said volume mapped to /var/lib/mysql, and then using a client such as WorkBench or a container such as adminer, to access your MySQL server and import your db file.

Comment: @MrFrenzoid This is what we ended up doing. Thank you for your response too. From what I can tell you establish your volume. Then when the docker container was up and running for the app we used docker exec -it app_container_name bash and connect to the MySQL terminal inside of this bash terminal. Here we were able to run the MySQL dump file to populate the db that persists through the volume established prior.